# Iframe tag not showing content in html

Tags: html, iframe, border, box

I am attempting to have a website inside my website using the iframe tag like this:

```
<iframe height="100%" width="100%" src="http://www.example.com/">
    <p>Your browser does not support the iframe element</p>
</iframe>
```

Unfortunately, this just shows a box or border. I would like it to show "example.com" inside my website.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems to work just fine https://codepen.io/pjabbott/pen/GEpWaL

Comment: I found out example.com works fine, but something like google.com doesn't. It reacts like I explained above. Maybe Google has embedding protected or turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Works for me.

https://jsfiddle.net/1a7y6n37/

Tested with:

```
<iframe height="100%" width="100%" src="https://www.w3schools.com">
    <p>Your browser does not support the iframe element</p>
</iframe>
```